# Done button not showing in iPhone when opening the select box in iframe

Tags: ios, html, cordova, iframe

I am trying to open a web url in iframe inside the PhoneGap application. When I choose a select box to open number pad the "Done" button is not showing to select the number. If I open the same url in safari then it shows the "Done" button.

Why is it not showing on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Install keyboard cordova plugin: https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard

And sets `Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);`.